# LaTeX help and command glossary

Tags: latex-misc

Is there any official site, mobile application or software for looking up latex (and its packages) commands and their syntax in it as Matlab Software done it in it's help. 
Brief description with some example for its syntax seems be very necessary for this excellent editor.
By the way there is [glossary of LaTeX on Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary)  but it isn't much user-friendly as I expected.

Comment: If you want some basic commands, try `texdoc latex2e`; for a list of symbols, try `texdoc symbols-a4`; for a list of TeX commands, try `texdoc texbytopic` (also, but different: http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html).  For specific packages, you need to look at the documentation of that package.

Comment: The Wikibooks entry you refer to is only for the `glossaries` package, not for LaTeX as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

Some editors have this functionality. For example with texstudio one can simply mouse hover a command/environment and for many (most?) one will get a brief description:

[image]